# RP in Bahrain less than six months valid for Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, austria

I'm travelling to Austria in December 2015 and my residence visa in Bahrain expires in April 2016. That leaves me with only 4 months validity on my visa from my date of return. This is less than the six months requisite mentioned on the website. Will i be refused a Schengen visa based on that? The Schengen site says I just need 90 days validity on my residence visa from my date of return - which I already do!

Please clarify!

Comment: Which website are you referring to?

Comment: http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-application-requirements/

Answer (score 1):

Always refer to the embassy at which you are applying. Austria does not have an embassy in Bahrain and visas for Austria are accepted at the French embassy.

[This page at the Embassy of France website](http://www.ambafrance-bh.org/Getting-an-Entry-Visa-to-France) has a list of requirements (linked PDFs) for non-bahraini passport holders applying for a visa.

According to that PDF, your Bahrain resident permit must be valid for 6 months in order for you to *apply for the visa*.